# trouble wiring smart ceiling fan switch.

Tags: wiring, switch

I recently was gifted a lot of home automation stuff and I was able to set everything up so far including outlets, thermostat, etc. Now I'm trying to tackle the light switch in my home office and its stumping me. any suggestions? any advice would be great thanks!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it just a light in your office, or a ceiling fan and a light?  If it's both, are they on one switch or two switches?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the "smart switch" your holding is worth using to begin with?

Comment: its a ceiling fan and light on a single gang. A couple of my friends are using the same light switch and they are very happy with it

Comment: Does the old switch have one or two switches on its face? Is this the only place you can control that light?

Comment: two switches. One for the fan and one for the light. and it is the only switch that controls the fan/light

Comment: we need to see the install instruction wiring diagram

Answer (score 1):

Connect

COM to L

A1 to L1

B1 to L2

You'll also need to connect the white wire in the box to the N terminal.

There should be a ground wire in the box as well, connect to the GND terminal

(There will be two white neutral wires in the box, connected to each other. They have to stay connected so you'll add a pigtail (a separate short wire) to that connection to provide the wire to the N terminal. Same thing for the bare copper ground wire.)